# In array how to check the maximum size of the list elements using perl

Tags: perl

```
my @str = qw /(I) (II) (XIII) (IV)/;
my @max = map { my $len=0; if(length($_)>$len){ $len = length($_);} } @str;
print $max;
```

output is `(XIII)` and length is `5`;

Could you please correct me where I have doing wrong in the above code.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Plese be more clear: what do you want and what is wrong?

Comment: Just to print the value and its length.

Comment: Then half my answer is invalid.

Comment: Maximum length in element of list in array...

Comment: using map function or anyother without using loop functions

Comment: If you want to learn about `map`, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform. It illustrates nicely what `map` can be used for.

Comment: `map` is a loop function. Don't be under any illusions. It iterates a list. Just like `for` does. You can abuse map to work a lot like `for`. You can with `grep` as well. But that doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to find the string length of the longest element in the array `@str`.

Your problem is that `map` is not doing what you think. It iterates the elements of `@str` and applies a modification to each of them. It returns a list of the modified elements. You are assigning that list to a scalar variable `$max`. A list in scalar context in Perl will be converted to the number of elements in that list, so you get `4`.

What you want is a `for` loop.

```
my @str = qw /(I) (II) (XIII) (IV)/;
my $max = 0;
for (@str) {
    $max = length($_) if length($_) > $max;
}
print $max;
```

This will print `6`, which is the correct length of `(XIII)`.

```
(XIII)
123456
```

Comment: I need to learn something about `map` and `grep` in my practical examples. thanks.

Comment: `map` is the wrong tool for your question. One could use `map` but one shouldn't use it here.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in the title, the cleaner option is to delegate this to [`List::Util::max`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#max):

```
use List::Util 'max';
print max map { length } @str;
```

The problem with the snippet in the question is that `$len` is local to each iteration of the `map` block, so effectively it gets reset to zero six times. The end result of this is that `$len` will correspond to the length of the last item in `@str`, which is why it doesn't do what you expect of it. You *could* do

```
my $len=0;
my @max = map { $len = length if $len < length } @str;
print $len;
```

but that's just lousy if you aren't meaningfully using `@max` for anything else.

Comment: That's so much cleaner and more idiomatic modern Perl than `for` loop.

Comment: ...but it creates unnecessary list. See my answer how to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`List::Util::reduce`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#reduce) instead of `map` in order to avoid creating unnecessary list of lengths:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/reduce max/;

my @str = qw /(I) (II) (XIII) (IV)/;
my $max = reduce { max($a, length($b)) } 0, @str;

print $max;
```